# CMS for static websites that allows inline editing of elements with specific class/data-* value

Tags: open-source, cms

There is a category of CMS that allow inline-editing of static pages, simply by adding a specific `class` to the elements that should be editable.

However, I only found proprietary and/or hosted solutions, for example: [*CushyCMS*](https://cushycms.com/), [*PageLime*](http://pagelime.com/), [*Surreal CMS*](http://surrealcms.com/), …

Is there a **FLOSS** alternative for **self-hosting** such a CMS?

Required features:

- **Inline editing** (= directly on the webpage) of elements that have a specific `class` or `data-*` value.
- Works with "**static sites**": create a usual, static HTML site, add the specific CMS attributes, upload it to the server, register it with the CMS, create user account that should be able to edit the site.
- Write the changes into the actual HTML files (no Ajax loading etc.).

  - It should always be possible to copy all files and host the site somewhere else, without using the CMS anymore.
  - Anonymously visiting the site should not require any processing or CMS calls etc., just deliver the static files.

Nice-to-have features:

- **Specialized forms/editors**: When adding the CMS attribute to `img`/`video`/`input` (for file upload)/etc. elements, use a suitable form.
- **Revisions**: save a history of all changes.
- **Backup**: allow exporting/importing the user-generated (= editable) content.
- **Multi-site** support: one installation can manage different websites (on different domains, with different user accounts).

Comment: Doesn't quite meet your requirements, so not worth an answer -- but you still might be interested to look at [Yellow CMS](http://datenstrom.se/yellow/) - Markdown files, PHP environment, on-page editing, dead-easy to use. I have no connections - use it for a couple simple academic course-support sites. Very handy.

Comment: Guess what... MediaWiki does this too! :P Seriously! 1) With file cache, the webserver  serves HTML directly, with no PHP calls. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User:Ilmari_Karonen/Performance_tuning#Use_the_file_cache 2) [$wgRawHtml](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRawHtml). 3) [Parsoid](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Parsoid) or [screenscraping](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Restoring_wiki_code_from_cached_HTML) or other tools (a Mozilla extension IIRC?) can import HTML into MediaWiki or even make it HTML-only. || Mostly kidding because (3) doesn't really exist yet in Parsoid

Comment: https://mavo.io may be close to what youre looking for

Answer (score 0):

As I have already written under a [similar question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14792/which-tiny-open-source-cms-for-a-single-page-website/14811), I would recommend [RazorCMS](http://www.razorcms.co.uk/). It is fast and efficient, extensible, actively developed.

As an alternative, try [CosmoCMS](http://www.cosmocms.org/), which is still in beta.

Comment: Do they allow an easy export to a fully static HTML website? Imagine I want to decommission the CMS and just serve a set of HTML files from some extremely cheap (or locked) host.

Comment: @Nemo You can always save static HTML files in a browser (ctrl-s)

Comment: I suppose that's sarcasm? I know how to download HTML for an entire site (usually people use httrack or wget-warc) but that's not an export/storage solution as asked by the question.