# Static site generator with GUI

Tags: linux, open-source, static-site-generator

I need a <s>CMS</s> **static site generator** for creating/editing static websites locally on my desktop.

Formal requirements: **FLOSS**; native installation on **GNU/Linux**; with **GUI**; must not require a local server (I don’t want to install a usual server-side CMS on the localhost).

#### 1) Adding a site

The tool should allow to manage several sites.

Ideally, it asks for a local folder (where all files of the site will be saved) and the server login data.

#### 2) Editing the code

I want to write all code (HTML, CSS, JS) myself. No WYSIWYG!

It should support a **template engine**, which could be really basic. Just let me add placeholders in the HTML template, where each placeholder creates a field in the GUI for adding/editing content. Bonus points for supporting field types (text field, textarea, select list with predefined values, image, etc.).

#### 3) Editing the content

The CMS should show me a **list/tree of all added pages** (and other created resources, like CSS files, HTML templates, robots.txt, .htaccess, maybe even images like the favicon).

When **adding a new page**, it would be great if I could choose an HTML template to be used (in case I have created several).

When **editing a page**, it should only show the fields for the content, not the full HTML of the page.

I don’t want a rich text editor; just let me enter plain text or even HTML or Markdown or something like that.

An internal search function would be great.

#### 4) Uploading the site

I don’t care how exactly the files are uploaded (FTP, SSH/SCP, …), as long as I don’t have to do it manually.

Ideally, it only uploads changed files.

Comment: I started writing such an application in c# a long time ago and got pretty far with it. Minus the upload and search features this is exactly what I was working on. I'm really surprised something like this just doesn't exist! It would be MUCH easier to write using a language for the web though such as php which could easily run within a VM... I may knock something together

Comment: Not really matching your various requirements, but probably worth a look: [TiddliWiki, a self-contained Wiki/CMS in a single HTML file](http://tiddlywiki.com/).

Comment: A combination of http://prose.io, Github, and a Jekyll Now fork should be all you need to multiple sites up and running without hitting the command line.

Comment: Is this very different from http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3020/cms-for-static-websites-that-allows-inline-editing-of-elements-with-specific-cla ?

Comment: @Nemo: Both have several overlapping feature requirements, but here I’m looking for a tool that runs locally on my desktop (so for a single user only), while in the linked question I’m looking for a self-hosted tool (for multiple users), so a possible solution would only apply to one question.

Answer (score 4):

I just found **[Publii](https://getpublii.com/)**:

> ... the app works locally you don't have to worry about security updates or manage databases.
>
> ... The goal of Publii is simplicity; no matter your skill level you'll find an intuitive user interface that, unlike static HTML generators, is easy-to-use.

The project is open-source, available at: https://github.com/GetPublii/Publii

Comment: nice one, but currently it's not i18n ready, both for user interface and content data. Developers say it's kinda huge task which would require a lot of work. They'll do but it's not a priority atm.

Comment: @Paolo, well, looks like GUI + static generation is a challenge on its own,.. I just shared, what I found, to help others also while doing their research

Answer (score 1):

[Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) is a static site generator.

It doesn't have a GUI, but allows you to create templates and content and allows markdown with a whole slew of customisation which a gui would find difficult to work around. You could easily use your favourite generic ide/text-editor for making the texts. Markdown is supported in a lot of editors.

The template language is Liquid (a ruby-based template language)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider looking into [DocPad](https://docpad.org/docs/intro) as a static site generator. It can be used with whatever markup tools you use (HTML, Jade, Haml, CSS, Sass, Less, etc.) and has a highly configurable build system.

As for the GUI you describe, it sounds like you might be looking for an IDE. One option in this department is [Eclipse for PHP Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/lunasr1) (even if you won't be using the PHP tooling components). With a library of extensions, it can do all that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the days, I tried [NVU](http://www.nvu.com/). This is stale now, but it links to [Kompozer](http://www.kompozer.net/).

The [features](http://www.kompozer.net/features.php) seem to be matching your requirements on several points, though maybe not on the content edition (but if you want to restrict the data that can be edited, maybe you *would* be better off with a CMS where you control who edits the content and who edits the rest of the code).

It is available on Windows and Linux.