# Which tiny open source CMS for a single page website?

Tags: open-source, php, cms

I am making a small one-page website, consisting of 3 sections and a contact form. I want to allow the client to edit each of the sections/blocks using WYSIWYG. Preferably they should be edited in-place, like in the discontinued Zimplit. The contact form should provide sending e-mails to the client. There will be no other pages, so the whole admin panel is not necessary.

It has to be in PHP, no MySQL, no PostgreSQL, and it has to be open source.

Wordpress, Drupal, CMSMadeSimple are too big for this.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried WonderCMS, SingleCMS, Cosmo CMS, InPlaceEditor and Raptor Editor, but so far the most suitable is [RazorCMS](http://www.razorcms.co.uk/):

- It's small and fast
- It's [actively developed](https://github.com/smiffy6969/razorCMS/releases)
- Doesn't need a database
- Has [extensions](https://github.com/smiffy6969/razorCMS-extensions)
- Provides in-place editing
- It's [open source](https://github.com/smiffy6969/razorCMS/)
- Can be installed via [Softaculous](http://www.softaculous.com/softaculous/apps/cms/razorCMS)